# escape special characters from connection string

Tags: c#

I have a connection string which contains a password with  special characters (ex. "Yaris!@#$%^&*()'?><"")  and i have tried to enclose the password between " but it doesn't seem to detect the double quote from the password when I try to read the password correctly from the command line arguments added in visual studio in debug mode .

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood correctly. I assume you specify your connection strings in **appsettings.json** like below,

```json
{
   "ConnectionStrings": {
      "Default": "Database=...; Server=...; Password="Yaris!@#$%^&*()'?><"""
   }
}
```

You should use **\** (escape character) before each **"** in your configuration. It should seem like below. Otherwise, your JSON won't be formatted correctly.

```json
{
   "ConnectionStrings": {
      "Default": "Database=...; Server=...; Password=\"Yaris!@#$%^&*()'?><\"\""
   }
}
```

You will be notice syntax highlighting in the first configuration seems wrong. Because it's doesn't know where to end the connection string value. When we add \ character before the starting quote (") it's basically ignored it.